# Printing number (count) or percentage of instances within Simple K Means clusters

Tags: java, weka, k-means

Trying to get the number of instances in each cluster as a count or percentage. I have wrote a cluster membership for the results of a Simple K Means WEKA clustering for loop below...

```
System.out.println("\n\nCluster membership:");
    for (int i = 0; i < m_instances.numInstances(); i++) { 
        try {
            int id = (int) m_instances.instance(i).index(i);
            temp.append("\nCluster " + clusterInstance(m_instances.instance(i)) + " contains Instance: " + id);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                } 
    }
```

Which outputs a result like this...

```
Cluster 0 contains Instance: 0
Cluster 0 contains Instance: 1
Cluster 0 contains Instance: 2
Cluster 0 contains Instance: 3
Cluster 0 contains Instance: 4
Cluster 1 contains Instance: 5
Cluster 1 contains Instance: 6
```

... and so on

Is there a way to use a for loop like my code above to get the number of instances inside each cluster to output something like this for example ...

```
Cluster 0 contains 5 Instances (71%)
Cluster 1 contains 2 Instances (28%)
```

Comment: Your percentages are incorrect. 5 out of 7 is ~71% and 2 out of 7 is ~28%. Your 67/33 percentages are 4 out of 6 and 2 out of 6 instead.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I am aware that my percentages. For the sake of minimising the question I only included a few results from my clustering. However, I will edit the percentages in the question according to your percentages. Thanks so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a map to keep track of the amount of instances per cluster, and then calculate the percentage per cluster:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
int amountOfInstances = m_instances.numInstances();
for (int i = 0; i < amountOfInstances; i++) {
  try {
    // A merge to either add a new cluster with count=1,
    // or increase the count by 1 for an already existing cluster in the map
    map.merge(clusterInstance(m_instances.instance(i)), 1, Integer::sum);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> keyValuePair : map.entrySet()){
  int cluster = keyValuePair.getKey();
  int count = keyValuePair.getValue();
  int percentage = (int)(100d / amountOfInstances * count);
  System.out.println("Cluster " + cluster + " contains " + count + " Instances (" + percentage + "%)");
}
```

Which would result in:

```
Cluster 0 contains 5 Instances (71%)
Cluster 1 contains 2 Instances (28%)
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##bZJNa4NAEIbv@RVDoLDGrdV@HfJ1KYWGEloI9BJy2JqN2URXWdcUCfntdlbN1rZBxJ2ZZ/Z9Z3DHDux6t95XlUiyVGnYYcIrtIi9wagXxizPYc6EPPYAsuIzFiHkmmn8HFKxhgRLZKGVkNFyBcwxGICQGiMhkZQhz2ECkn812aNPA3pL7@g9faCPp1GHD@Mi11z9xc9PQAPEa37OsvFMah5xRaE9TNFL1ra@sHxrmClxrACwJC2kftvMOrasRS/mMtLbht6kipgOMfFHIMb/IBCu204KRtVLuIo4OftfihWFwBobDvMiaX2celYA/XnPUqvywiR7Xn6wuODvTCgY1hLcoAuuiWOVjcVWE0fp9ngR16@8PE/fomb8C2Ad/EYzrkIUZBFH3qzCIYHvr@HmwhIHzcW2f1GiocRLC@1l@FvoWJL@U@uyD6517GIUpiiC620KtT@T/rmcmELHDVavnL5dpnlPVfUN)